# How to show post list based on taxonomy term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a CPT named “football_fixture”.This CPT has taxonomy named “competition”, and this taxonomy has different terms , laliga, eng.
I want to show my post as follow:
laliga:
List of all posts published including above terms.
eng:
List of all posts published including above terms.
I am using following codes but it show the content as showed in the image1.
[image]

I want the post like image 2:
[image]
image1:
 Here is the codes I am using:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Fixture
* Description: The template for displaying all  posts and attachments
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php


$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'football_fixture',
                'paged' => $paged,

            );

    query_posts( $args );
?>

<?php if(have_posts()): ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $col; ?>">


        <?php while(have_posts()): ?>
            <?php the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                 <?php
                    $id         = get_the_ID();
                    $date       = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_date','', $post->ID);
                    $time       = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_time','', $post->ID );
                    $competition = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_competition_cats','', $post->ID );
                    $team_a     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'match_details_home_team', true );
                    $team_b     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'match_details_away_team', true );

                ?>
                <div class="fixture-item">
                    <div class="fixture-info clearfix">
                        <p class="pull-left match-date"><?php echo ($date); ?></p>
                        <p class="pull-left match-date">
                        <?php 

                        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'competition' ); // 'taxonomy' field doesn't store term IDs in the custom fields, instead, it sets post terms
                        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
                            $content = '<ul>';
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $content .= sprintf(
                                    '<li><a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a></li>',
                                    get_term_link( $term, 'tax_slug' ),
                                    $term->name,
                                    $term->name
                                );
                            }
                            $content .= '</ul>';
                            echo $content;
                        }
                        ?>

                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="media">

                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4><?php echo $team_a; ?></h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-4 match-time">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $time; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <div class="media">

                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="pull-right"><?php echo $team_b; ?></h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--/#post-->
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php 
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom templates, First you have to fetch all terms for your custom post type.

You can use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) to retrive terms in taxonomy

If you are using wordpress prior to 4.5

```
$terms = get_terms( 'competition' , array(
    'hide_empty' => false
) );
```

OR if you are using wordpress prior to 4.5.0 or later

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'competition',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

Next Build Term name lists:

```
$termNames = array();
$count = count( $terms );
if ( $count > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $termNames[] = $term->name;
    }
}
```

Next loop trough each terms and query posts for the current terms & then run the loop:

```
foreach($termNames as $termName) :

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'football_fixture',
    'competition' => $termName,
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
query_posts( $args );
if(have_posts()): ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $col; ?>">
        <h2><?php echo $termName; ?></h2>
        <?php while(have_posts()):  the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
             <?php
                $id         = get_the_ID();
                $date       = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_date','', $post->ID);
                $time       = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_time','', $post->ID );
                $competition = rwmb_meta( 'pb_match_competition_cats','', $post->ID );
                $team_a     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'match_details_home_team', true );
                $team_b     = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'match_details_away_team', true );

            ?>
            <div class="fixture-item">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4><?php echo $team_a; ?></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-4 match-time">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php echo $time; ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="pull-right"><?php echo $team_b; ?></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/#post-->
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php 
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [query for your posts which have a the associated custom taxonomy term(s)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters),

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'football_fixture',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'competition',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array($term_id),  //put more term ids if required
      ),
    ),
  );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($query->have_posts()){
  while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query->post->ID ) . '</li>';
  }

  // Restore original Post Data once finished, IMPORTANT
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

now, you need to get the `$term_id` of your term to make sure the above query works, in your example you have the following line at the top,

```
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

however, [the function `get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) will only return the the term_id for a taxonomy template, what you are trying to do is display this in a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#file-organization-of-page-templates), as your page header starts with,

```
 <?php
 /**
 * Template Name: Fixture    -- this indicates that you are building a page template
```

so you will not have access to any term id.  You have 2 options to get the results you are looking for,

- hard code the term ID in your page template, or pass it as an argument in the URL attribute
- create a [taxonomy archive template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies), so you can use your custom taxonomy terms directly into your menu, users will click the term link and WordPress will parse the term id to your page.

### Putting it all together,

I would recommend the second option.  Create a new file called `taxonomy-competition.php` and save it in your root theme or child theme folder with the following content,

```
<?php
/**
 * Taxonomy 'competition' archive template
 */
get_header();

$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'football_fixture',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'competition',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms'    => array($term_id),  //put more term ids if required
      ),
    ),
  );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo '<ul>';
if($query->have_posts()){
  while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query->post->ID ) . '</li>';
  }

  // Restore original Post Data once finished, IMPORTANT
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
echo '</ul>';

get_footer();
```

This will display the list post titles which are organised under the given term.

To use this on the front end, add the custom taxonomy `competition` terms you want to display your [navigational menu in the dashboard](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-navigation-menu-in-wordpress-beginners-guide/).  If you are unable to see your taxonomy menu option, make sure it is selected in the 'Screen Options' tab at the top of the dashboard page.